# 'type' object is not iterable in using django_enums

Tags: python, django, enums

I tried to use [django_enums](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-enums/) and got an error with **list(cls)** when making migrations:

```
(venv:SFS)rita@rita-notebook:~/Serpentarium/ServiceForServices/project/serviceforservices$ python manage.py makemigrations
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/rita/Serpentarium/ServiceForServices/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/rita/Serpentarium/ServiceForServices/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/rita/Serpentarium/ServiceForServices/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/rita/Serpentarium/ServiceForServices/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/rita/Serpentarium/ServiceForServices/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/rita/Serpentarium/ServiceForServices/project/serviceforservices/service/models.py", line 84, in <module>
    class EmployeesStatus(models.Model):
  File "/home/rita/Serpentarium/ServiceForServices/project/serviceforservices/service/models.py", line 86, in EmployeesStatus
    status = enum.EnumField(StatusEnum, default=StatusEnum.AT)
  File "/home/rita/Serpentarium/ServiceForServices/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_enums/enum.py", line 53, in __init__
    kwargs['max_length'] = self.enum.get_max_length()
  File "/home/rita/Serpentarium/ServiceForServices/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_enums/enum.py", line 39, in get_max_length
    return len(max(list(cls), key=(lambda x: len(x.key))).key)
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

I installed django-enums, enum and six:

```
(venv:SFS)rita@rita-notebook:~/Serpentarium/ServiceForServices/project/serviceforservices$ pip install django-enums
(venv:SFS)rita@rita-notebook:~/Serpentarium/ServiceForServices/project/serviceforservices$ pip install enum
(venv:SFS)rita@rita-notebook:~/Serpentarium/ServiceForServices/project/serviceforservices$ pip install six
```

Using in Models.py:

```
...
from django_enums import enum

...
class StatusEnum(enum.Enum):
__order__ = 'AT BT BC AC'  # for python 2

AT = (u'АВ', u'Активен временно')
BT = (u'БВ', u'Блокирован временно')
BC = (u'БП', u'Блокирован постоянно')
AC = (u'АП', u'Активен постоянно')

class EmployeesStatus(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    status = enum.EnumField(StatusEnum, default=StatusEnum.AT)
```

It seems like project is alive, it also was updated for Django 1.10 and compartible with python 2 allegedly. So, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please Share the code of views.py file from where the error is raising.

Comment: post your code of `viwes.py`

Comment: Your traceback shows this error is happening in the EmployeesStatus model, not EventLog.

Comment: Post your `StatusEnum` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use the backported enum from the 3.4 stdlib, but you installed `enum` -- you need to install `enum34`.